# What is "effective turning level"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric

I am playng evil drow priestess of Lloth with alternative class feature "drow cleric".

> Level: 1st.
>
> Replaces: If you select this class feature, you do not gain the
>   standard cleric's ability to turn or rebuke undead.
>
> Benefit: You can rebuke or command vermin as an evil cleric rebukes or
>   commands undead. When commanding spiders, you gain a +4 bonus to your
>   effective turning level.
>
> This ability otherwise works exactly as rebuke undead. You can use
>   this ability in place of turn or rebuke undead for the purpose of
>   qualifying for divine feats.

Currently I am 1st level.

How does it affects when I rebuke and command spiders? I supposed it means that my cleric level is 5 whem I am rebuking and commanding spiders. I think at least it means that when I roll 1d20+chaMod and look at table, "cleric level" there is actually "effective turning level" and equals 5, so if i roll 0, i can rebuke spider of 1 (=5-4) hd and so on. I am not sure if I can command total 2.5 hd of spiders. It seems a bit too cheesy at 1st lvl. Or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The +4 bonus to effective turning level means you treat your cleric level as being 4 higher than it actually is for all purposes related to turning or rebuking undead. The term “effective turning level” emphasizes that this is different from your *actual* cleric level; this bonus does not give you four extra levels, just lets you count as four levels higher for turning.

Comment: Does he add the effective level to the damage roll that determines the total HD?
Turning Damage
If your roll on Table: Turning Undead is high enough to let you turn at least some of the undead within 60 feet, roll 2d6 + your cleric level + your Charisma modifier for turning damage. That’s how many total Hit Dice of undead you can turn.

Comment: @Thorborn762 All purposes related to turning or rebuking undead; yes.

Comment: @Thorborn762 Well, strictly speaking, no, since he's replaced it with rebuke/command spiders, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: My main doubt about question how many hd of spiders I can command. Reading " At any one time, the cleric may command any number of undead whose total Hit Dice do not exceed his level." Level menshioned here should also be "effective tuning level", but it means that I can have two 2hd spiders under my command. It's sounds too much so I can hardly believe it was so intended.

Comment: Is it possible this is more complicated than this, what with the class feature only specifying *commanding* spiders yet not specifying *rebuking* them?

Comment: @Izulle Consider if you were turning undead you could have 5 1HD skeletons, I think that's just how it works=) #believe

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, I am not interested in considering that they were splitting hairs that finely.

Comment: After spending a few thousand words trying this out, I think all but the most diligently organized DM would suicide were he to try to run an actual encounter of a mixed group of spiders and other vermin against a master of spiders cleric using this reading, even though doing so *is* possible. However, given the complexity of determining the results of turning checks and turning damage on such a mixed group, I maintain it's *a lot* easier to *play* this ability as a bonus *only* to command spiders specifically rather than rebuke spiders generally.